# Datagridviews in TabControl

Tags: datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with four tabs, each tab containing a datagridview.

To verify that all the data in the four datagridviews is correct I do a scan of each datagridview to check for missing files etc and if incorrect I recolour the background using:

pBadStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle
   pBadStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
   .
   .
   dgvAssetInput.Item(1, i).Style = pBadStyle

This all works fine for the datagridview in the first tab. The incorrect values are coloured pink. For the other datagridviews nothing is done. The style remains unchanged.

I tried running the re-style process when the user selects the tab thinking that Windows isn't going to set a style that can't be seen by the user but this failed also.

I've looked for some styling property setting that is in the first tab datagridview and not in the others but all their properties are identical.

Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ma not sure the actual controls are created until you switch to that tab. You can try and hook into the [OnDataBindingComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.ondatabindingcomplete(v=vs.100).aspx) to see when the controls actually load the data.
My guess is that those grids are not created at the time you want to modify them.